# Sqoop Import fails

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm facing an issue in importing data from `SQL Server` to `HDFS` using `SQOOP`. I'm working on Windows platform and have installed `HDInsights` on my machine.

This is the error.

```
Error reading task outputhttp://hadoopserver.in.g-c-i.com:50060/tasklog?
plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201302051321_0012_m_000001_0&filter=stdout Error
reading task outputhttp://hadoopserver.in.g-c-i.com:50060/tasklog?
plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201302051321_0012_m_000001_0&filter=stderr
```

Help needed.
Thanks

Comment: Would you mind sharing entire Sqoop command and log generated with parameter --verbose?